# How to store DT_R8 in a variable in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package to read data from a source table which has float data type. It is shown as DT_R8 in SSIS (under External Columns), i want to store the value in a variable in SSIS package and i'm using Double datatype, but it does not work and throws this error...

> The type of the value being assigned to variable "User::varDBVAL"
>   differs from the current variable type

Can someone please suggest a possible solution, I could only find the data type mapping between SSIS and SQL Server but not for data types on SSIS.

Thanks
john

Comment: Execute sql task or is this in the data flow? Using an OLE DB provider or ADO.NET ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do this just fine. I generated a package with 2 execute sql tasks: One to POC Maverick's way and one to do what I believe you are doing.

[image]

As you can see, 4 Variables created: Mav, Query, QueryMav and varDBVAL. Mav is an integer with an expression attached to it assigning a value of zero. The two queries are simple as can be - a select of a constant value to ensure we have the correct type generated.

I believe Maverick is stating that setting the expression on a Variable allows you to overwrite that value wherever you wish. What this screenshot is demonstrating is that while it does *not* error out when the first Execute SQL Task fires, the overwrite of the value of @[User::Maverick] does not actually stick. The task assigned a value of `1` to the Variable but the expression overrides that value and supplies `0`

[image]

The Execute SQL Task for a float/double is straight forward. I return a single row of data based on my source query

[image]

In the Variable's tab, I assign the zeroth column to my variable `@[User::varDBVAL]` and execution works just fine

[image]

### Biml for reproduction

If you have [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com) installed, if you edit the connection string to point to a valid SQL Server instance, you should be able to generate the above package and verify that the assignment of a float/double value into an SSIS Variable.

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Connections>
        <OleDbConnection Name="CM_OLE" ConnectionString="Data Source=localhost\dev2012;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;"></OleDbConnection>
    </Connections>
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="so_2176077" ConstraintMode="Linear">
            <Variables>
                <Variable DataType="Double" Name="varDBVAL">0</Variable>
                <Variable DataType="String" Name="Query">SELECT CAST(1.0123 AS float) AS dbVal </Variable>
                <Variable DataType="Int32" Name="Mav" EvaluateAsExpression="true">0</Variable>
                <Variable DataType="String" Name="QueryMav">SELECT 1 AS Mav</Variable>
            </Variables>
            <Tasks>
                <ExecuteSQL ConnectionName="CM_OLE" Name="SQL MavTest" ResultSet="SingleRow">
                    <VariableInput VariableName="User.QueryMav"></VariableInput>
                    <Results>
                        <Result VariableName="User.Mav" Name="0"></Result>
                    </Results>
                </ExecuteSQL>

                <ExecuteSQL ConnectionName="CM_OLE" Name="SQL AssignValue" ResultSet="SingleRow">
                    <VariableInput VariableName="User.Query"></VariableInput>
                    <Results>
                        <Result VariableName="User.varDBVAL" Name="0"></Result>
                    </Results>
                </ExecuteSQL>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

### Reference

- [Integration Services Data Types](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036.aspx)
- [SQL Server Data Type Precedence](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx)

### Edits

The results are the same whether I used 2012 or 2008.

[image]

If the explicit CAST worked, then the root cause was you weren't operating on a floating point number. It was probably a decimal/numeric which would explain the error message as a that is a different type than a float.

The 2012 way of determining your data type is through the system stored proc `sys.sp_describe_first_result_set` or the table valued function `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set`. Below you can see the difference between the default data type assigned to a number with decimal places versus an explicit cast to type.

```
SELECT 
    T.name AS column_name
,   T.column_ordinal
,   T.system_type_name
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'SELECT 1.0123 AS Defaults, CAST(1.10123 AS float) AS Explicits;', NULL, NULL) AS T;
```

The default interpretation of 1.0123 is going to be as numeric(5,4) and only be explicitly casting to the floating point data type do I actually get a float.

[image]

There might be a graceful way in 2005/2008 but I'd just dump the query into a table `SELECT ... INTO dbo.Temporary WHERE NULL = NULL` and then look at the corresponding metadata.

Comment: Add one more step that is The variable to be dynamic- CLick the variable > GO to properties > Expression and drag the User::Parametername.. It should stick now

Comment: @Maverick I think it'd improve your answer if you could put a simple example up. You might have some really cool trick that I've never seen but it appears that neither dotnetjohn or myself are understanding the intricacies of your approach.

Comment: Maverick,  billinkc thanks a heap for you both for your help. The CAST() did the trick. But the value i'm querying from database is Float type only. I still don't understand why i have to convert a FLOAT datatype to FLOAT. many thanks for telling abt BIDS Helper, i never knew this before.

Comment: What i noticed is TypeConversionMode property would have done the trick for me if i was working on SQL 2012, sadly i'm still on 2008 R2. It tries to convert the result to the data type of the variable it is mapped to. in the end I learned a lot with this problem...

Comment: @billinkc: I am just wondering why is there a negative score to my answer.. I am not mad about someone downgrading my answer but i feel shame on these people.

Answer (score -1):

One of the way you can do it is

1) Click on variable User::varDBVA > Go to variable properties and Drag the user variable in the expression and Evaluate value.

2) Click EvaluateAsExpression as TRUE

3) You can assign to this variable anywhere in the package.

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: Hi Sorry i did not understand what you mean, i'm assigning the output(DT_R8) of Execute SQL statement to the Double variable varDBVAL, but it throws the error i mentioned.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand your approach @Maverick. When I create an Execute SQL Task and assign a value to a Variable which has EvaluateAsExpression set to True, that assignment is valid but doesn't stick because the value of the variable is going to be the expression, not whatever you assign to it.

Comment: @billinkc :- That is beauty about variable and expressions. Let suppose you assign a value to a variable you can dynamically change it in run time or you can use as it..

Comment: @Maverick i tried but still throws the error. The output of my SQL task is DT_R8 and not an expression, so i'm wondering how EvaluateAsExpression will fix the data type mismatch problem.

Comment: @Maverick In my answer below, did I accurately capture what this answer indicates should work?

Answer (score -1):

[image]

[image]

Sorry I am not that organize..Hope this will help !!!

Comment: Since this is part of your other answer, it'd be best served by being edited into that response instead of listed as a separate answer. That said, varDBVAL is a string data type that contains an expression on the *query*. How does that solve the problem of assigning a floating point number into an SSIS Variable?

Answer (score -2):

Give a try with following steps::

1. Create SSIS Variable.
   [image]
2. Drag an Execute SQL task and configure like below.
   [image]
3. Map parameter like below.
   [image]
4. Execute package now by keeping break point on Post Execute. Check value for that variable. Like below.
   [image]

And let me know your comments/results.

Comment: Your solution is not assigning a value to varDBVAL in what you're demonstrating. Instead, you're using it as a parameter to the query